# console.log not working inside a nativescript view model function

Tags: nativescript

I am very new to nativescript. I have tried to debug a sample app through the console.log. It's a view model page code

```
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;
console.log(1);
function getMessage(counter) {

if (counter <= 0) {
    return "Hoorraaay! You unlocked the NativeScript clicker achievement!";
} else {
    return counter + " taps left";
}
}

function createViewModel() {
console.log(2);
var viewModel = new Observable();
viewModel.counter = 42;
viewModel.message = getMessage(viewModel.counter);

viewModel.onTap = function() {

    this.counter--;
    this.set("message", getMessage(this.counter));
}

return viewModel;
}

exports.createViewModel = createViewModel;
```

The first log is appearing. But not the log 2. But I think the createViewModel method is being called.
I am using this command to execute my app already opened in genemotion

```
tns livesync android --watch --debug
```

Nor

```
tns emulate android
```

works.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The second log statement is inside a function. It will be executed when that function is executed. Somewhere you need to execute `createViewModel()`

Comment: HI Brad, exports.createViewModel = createViewModel this line (the last one in my snippet) should trigger the function. And it triggers, But I can't see the log

Comment: It won't execute it's only definition of function it will fire only if you run that function on it's own or when you will assign function to variable and it's what Brad said.

Comment: Exporting a function doesn't execute it, just FYI

Comment: @Abhisek_Malakar create base app with `tns create testApp` and place the logs as shown... in the base template the createViewModel is  called when we are attaching the page.bindingContext so you will see both of your logs executed as expected.